# Is there a way to access the original task passed to asyncio.as_completed?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to pull tasks from an asyncio queue and call a given error handler if an exception occurred. Queued items are given as dictionaries (enqueued by `enqueue_task`) which contain the task, a possible error handler, and any args/kwargs the error handler may require. Since I'd like to handle any errors as the tasks complete, I map each task to the dequeued dictionary and attempt to access it if an exception occurs.

```
async def _check_tasks(self):
    try:
        while self._check_tasks_task or not self._check_task_queue.empty():
            tasks = []
            details = {}
            try:
                while len(tasks) < self._CHECK_TASKS_MAX_COUNT:
                    detail = self._check_task_queue.get_nowait()
                    task = detail['task']
                    tasks.append(task)
                    details[task] = detail
            except asyncio.QueueEmpty:
                pass

            if tasks:
                for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
                    try:
                        await task
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.exception('')
                        detail = details[task]
                        error_handler = detail.get('error_handler')
                        error_handler_args = detail.get('error_handler_args', [])
                        error_handler_kwargs = detail.get('error_handler_kwargs', {})

                        if error_handler:
                            logger.info('calling error handler')
                            if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(error_handler):
                                self.enqueue_task(
                                    task=error_handler(
                                        e,
                                        *error_handler_args,
                                        **error_handler_kwargs
                                    )
                                )
                            else:
                                error_handler(e, *error_handler_args, **error_handler_kwargs)
                        else:
                            logger.exception(f'Exception encountered while handling task: {str(e)}')
            else:
                await asyncio.sleep(self._QUEUE_EMPTY_SLEEP_TIME)
    except:
        logger.exception('')


def enqueue_task(self, task, error_handler=None, error_handler_args=[],
                 error_handler_kwargs={}):
    if not asyncio.isfuture(task):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(task)

    self._app.gateway._check_task_queue.put_nowait({
        'task': task,
        'error_handler': error_handler,
        'error_handler_args': error_handler_args,
        'error_handler_kwargs': error_handler_kwargs,
    })
```

However, when an exception occurs, it appears the task being used as a key is not found in the `details` dictionary, and I receive the following error:

```
KeyError: <generator object as_completed.<locals>._wait_for_one at 0x7fc2d1cea308>
Exception encountered while handling task: <generator object as_completed.<locals>._wait_for_one at 0x7fc2d1cea308>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app/gateway/gateway.py", line 64, in _check_tasks
    detail = details[task]
KeyError: <generator object as_completed.<locals>._wait_for_one at 0x7fc2d1cea308>
```

When `task` is yielded by `asyncio.as_completed`, it seems to be a generator

```
<generator object as_completed.<locals>._wait_for_one at 0x7fc2d1cea308>
```

when I expect it to be a task

```
<Task pending coro=<GatewayL1Component._save_tick_to_stream() running at /app/app/gateway/l1.py:320> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc2d4380d98>()]>>
```

Why is `task` a generator instead of the original task after being yielded by `asyncio.as_complete`? Is there a way to access the original task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is task a generator instead of the original task after being yielded by `asyncio.as_complete`?

The problem is that `as_completed` is not an [async iterator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) (which you'd exhaust with `async for`), but an ordinary iterator. Where an async iterator's `__aiter__` can suspend while awaiting an async event, an ordinary iterator's `__iter__` must immediately provide a result. It obviously cannot yield a completed task because no tasks have yet had time to complete, so it yields an awaitable object that *actually* waits for a task to complete. This is the object that looks like a generator.

As another consequence of the implementation, awaiting this task gives you the result of the original task rather than a reference to the task object - in contrast to the original [`concurrent.futures.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed). This makes `asyncio.as_completed` less intuitive and harder to use, and [there is a bug report](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77714) that argues that `as_completed` should be made usable as an async iterator as well, providing the correct semantics. (This can be done in a backward-compatible way.)

> Is there a way to access the original task?

As a workaround, you can create an async version of `as_completed` by wrapping the original task into a coroutine that finishes when the task does, and has the task as its result:

```
async def as_completed_async(futures):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    wrappers = []
    for fut in futures:
        assert isinstance(fut, asyncio.Future)  # we need Future or Task
        # Wrap the future in one that completes when the original does,
        # and whose result is the original future object.
        wrapper = loop.create_future()
        fut.add_done_callback(wrapper.set_result)
        wrappers.append(wrapper)

    for next_completed in asyncio.as_completed(wrappers):
        # awaiting next_completed will dereference the wrapper and get
        # the original future (which we know has completed), so we can
        # just yield that
        yield await next_completed
```

That should allow you to get the original tasks - here is a simple test case:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fut1 = loop.create_task(asyncio.sleep(.2))
    fut1.t = .2
    fut2 = loop.create_task(asyncio.sleep(.3))
    fut2.t = .3
    fut3 = loop.create_task(asyncio.sleep(.1))
    fut3.t = .1
    async for fut in as_completed_async([fut1, fut2, fut3]):
        # using the `.t` attribute shows that we've got the original tasks
        print('completed', fut.t)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by using `asyncio.gather` instead:

```
async def _check_tasks(self):
    while self._check_tasks_task or not self._check_task_queue.empty():
        tasks = []
        details = []
        try:
            while len(tasks) < self._CHECK_TASKS_MAX_COUNT:
                detail = self._check_task_queue.get_nowait()
                task = detail['task']
                tasks.append(task)
                details.append(detail)
        except asyncio.QueueEmpty:
            pass

        if tasks:
            results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
            for i, result in enumerate(results):
                if isinstance(result, Exception):
                    detail = details[i]
                    error_handler = detail.get('error_handler')
                    error_handler_args = detail.get('error_handler_args', [])
                    error_handler_kwargs = detail.get('error_handler_kwargs', {})

                    if error_handler:
                        logger.info('calling error handler')
                        if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(error_handler):
                            self.enqueue_task(
                                task=error_handler(
                                    result,
                                    *error_handler_args,
                                    **error_handler_kwargs
                                )
                            )
                        else:
                            error_handler(
                                result, *error_handler_args, **error_handler_kwargs
                            )
                    else:
                        msg = f'Exception encountered while handling task: {str(result)}'
                        logger.exception(msg)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(self._QUEUE_EMPTY_SLEEP_TIME)
```